# Ubuntu 16.04 cannot detect VGA monitor

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, nouveau, vga

I am simply trying to connect a VGA-VGA monitor to my HP Zbook laptop running 16.04 Xenial, and doesn't matter what I try the monitor won't get detected. I have tried the following:

1. Ran `xrandr`: says "Failed to get size of gamma for output default". That's a dead end as far as I can see. Following is the output or xrandr:

`HP-ZBook-15-G3:~$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*`

2. Ran `arandr`: It shows up some UI for screen resolution/position adjustment but cannot find any option to add display or similar.
3. Switched display drivers: I was running nouveau and switched to nvidia-390, but got stuck in the login loop as is common when you run Nvidia driver on Ubuntu. Had to purge nvidia drivers and ran reconfigure lightdm to get desktop back.
4. `lshw -C display` says `display UNCLAIMED` for both `VGA Compatible controller: Intel Corporation`, and `VGA Compatible Controller: GM107GLM [Quadro M100M] Nvidia corporation`.
5. In *System Settings* -> *Software & Updates* -> *Additional Drivers* I have Nouveau X server, and 3 Nvidia drivers: 384.130, 387.34, 390.48, and switching to Nvidia causes a login loop as I mentioned above.
6. And of course I have gone to *System Settings* -> *Display*, but it only shows my laptop screen as the only display detected.

I would really like to get my monitor working with my laptop, but I feel I'm stuck in a dead end.

Comment: Type `xrandr` in the command line then copy and paste the output into your question. Maybe someone else will see something you missed. I'm using HDMI instead of VGA so may not be able to help much.

Comment: Is that an ancient VGA monitor (with no DDC support) and/or an ancient cable (which does not connect the DDC pins) being used? Such a setup cannot transmit monitor specs to the graphics card/chip, and X might (for very good reasons - some 1980s/1990s monitors can be physically wrecked if you feed them incompatible signals) not try to wild guess, instead expecting full manual configuration.